# How to protect/hide R.xml.global_tracker file in Android project

Tags: android, xml, security, google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics in my Android Application. I want to give this project to my friend but i dont want him to see my R.xml.global_tracker file as it contains my ga_trackingId. How can i hide/protect my R.xml.global_tracker file?

Comment: use some dummy values there before giving him or create separate analytics id for it

Comment: My friend will be building this project. I want google analytics to work but he should be not knowing that. Is there any way to completely hide the implementation of google analytics, I have converted JAVA files to .jar but what about the XML's